# Birt : Add bookmarks to Report in PDF Format

Tags: birt

Can anyone tell me How to add Bookmarks to the Report generated in PDF format in Birt.  Bookmark should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get into the design view of that report and then their is tab for bookmarks.U can add from thr.

Comment: ya.got it.Thnks for the answer !!